# iwlwifi related boot warning and trace

Tags: networking, kernel, 22.04, iwlwifi

Should I be concerned about this boot warning? The only downside I've experienced so far is that sometimes after boot, the wifi card is not recognized and not loaded, but a quick reboot almost always fixes it immediately.

```
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: ------------[ cut here ]------------
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: WARNING: CPU: 4 PID: 1168 at drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwl-nvm-parse.c:711 iwl_init_he_hw_capab+0x34a/0x360 [iwlwifi]
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: Modules linked in: snd_hda_codec_realtek(+) snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio mei_hdcp mei_pxp snd_hda_intel(+) intel_rapl_msr snd_intel_dspcfg binfmt_misc iwlmvm(+) snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_core mac80211 snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_seq_midi chromeos_p
store(-) snd_seq_midi_event libarc4 snd_rawmidi snd_seq cmdlinepart processor_thermal_device_pci_legacy iwlwifi snd_seq_device processor_thermal_device spi_nor snd_timer rapl processor_thermal_rfim acer_wmi input_leds intel_cstate serio_raw intel_wmi_thunderbolt mei_me processor_thermal_mbox mtd cfg80211 s
parse_keymap ee1004 wmi_bmof snd processor_thermal_rapl hid_multitouch(+) mei intel_rapl_common soundcore intel_pch_thermal intel_soc_dts_iosf int3400_thermal int3403_thermal mac_hid acpi_thermal_rel int340x_thermal_zone acpi_pad acer_wireless sch_fq_codel coretemp msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport ramoops p
store_blk reed_solomon pstore_zone efi_pstore ip_tables x_tables autofs4 r8153_ecm cdc_ether
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: usbnet hid_logitech_hidpp r8152 hid_logitech_dj mii usbhid uas usb_storage i915 drm_buddy i2c_algo_bit ttm drm_display_helper cec rc_core drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops hid_generic crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel inte
l_lpss_pci crypto_simd i2c_hid_acpi nvme spi_intel_pci i2c_i801 r8169 ahci intel_lpss i2c_nvidia_gpu cryptd xhci_pci drm i2c_hid nvme_core spi_intel i2c_smbus realtek libahci idma64 i2c_ccgx_ucsi xhci_pci_renesas hid wmi video pinctrl_cannonlake
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: CPU: 4 PID: 1168 Comm: modprobe Tainted: P O 5.19.0-41-generic #42~22.04.1-Ubuntu
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: Hardware name: Acer Predator PT315-52/Hatch_CMS, BIOS V1.09 01/04/2021
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: RIP: 0010:iwl_init_he_hw_capab+0x34a/0x360 [iwlwifi]
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: Code: 44 89 28 0f b7 4b 5c 83 c2 01 48 83 e8 80 39 ca 7c ed e9 21 fd ff ff 48 8d 86 a0 02 00 00 e9 58 fd ff ff 0f 0b e9 0e fd ff ff <0f> 0b e9 20 ff ff ff 0f 0b e9 47 ff ff ff e8 e3 c4 c2 d0 0f 1f 00
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffacde80e43898 EFLAGS: 00010246
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff8c0297df8168 RCX: 0000000000000000
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 0000000000000000
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: RBP: ffffacde80e438f8 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: R10: 0000000000000003 R11: 0000000000000003 R12: ffff8c028ca78028
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: R13: ffff8c0297df8000 R14: 0000000000000003 R15: 0000000000000003
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: FS: 00007fe544799c40(0000) GS:ffff8c09be300000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: CS: 0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: CR2: 000056147a291710 CR3: 000000011be0e002 CR4: 00000000007706e0
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: PKRU: 55555554
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: Call Trace:
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: <TASK>
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: iwl_init_sbands+0x265/0x2d0 [iwlwifi]
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: iwl_get_nvm+0x25f/0x2d0 [iwlwifi]
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: iwl_run_unified_mvm_ucode+0x209/0x250 [iwlmvm]
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: ? iwl_run_unified_mvm_ucode+0x209/0x250 [iwlmvm]
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: ? iwl_read32+0x21/0x90 [iwlwifi]
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: ? 0xffffffffc104f000
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: iwl_run_init_mvm_ucode+0x29/0x40 [iwlmvm]
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: iwl_mvm_start_get_nvm+0xad/0x280 [iwlmvm]
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: iwl_op_mode_mvm_start+0x7e4/0xa40 [iwlmvm]
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: _iwl_op_mode_start+0x75/0xe0 [iwlwifi]
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: iwl_opmode_register+0x6d/0xf0 [iwlwifi]
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: ? 0xffffffffc1006000
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: iwl_mvm_init+0x3a/0x1000 [iwlmvm]
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: ? 0xffffffffc1006000
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: do_one_initcall+0x46/0x220
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: ? kmem_cache_alloc_trace+0x1a6/0x330
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: do_init_module+0x52/0x220
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: load_module+0xb56/0xd40
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: ? security_kernel_post_read_file+0x5c/0x80
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: ? kernel_read_file+0x245/0x2a0
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: __do_sys_finit_module+0xcc/0x150
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: ? __do_sys_finit_module+0xcc/0x150
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: __x64_sys_finit_module+0x18/0x30
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: do_syscall_64+0x59/0x90
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: ? exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0x3b/0xd0
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x2a/0x50
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: ? do_syscall_64+0x69/0x90
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: ? exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0x3b/0xd0
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x2a/0x50
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: ? do_syscall_64+0x69/0x90
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: ? do_syscall_64+0x69/0x90
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x63/0xcd
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: RIP: 0033:0x7fe543f1ea3d
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: Code: 5b 41 5c c3 66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 f3 0f 1e fa 48 89 f8 48 89 f7 48 89 d6 48 89 ca 4d 89 c2 4d 89 c8 4c 8b 4c 24 08 0f 05 <48> 3d 01 f0 ff ff 73 01 c3 48 8b 0d c3 a3 0f 00 f7 d8 64 89 01 48
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: RSP: 002b:00007ffe0f2cb798 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000139
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000561b8211e110 RCX: 00007fe543f1ea3d
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000561b8211eb70 RDI: 0000000000000002
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: RBP: 0000000000040000 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000002
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: R10: 0000000000000002 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000561b8211eb70
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: R13: 0000561b8211e240 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000561b82128870
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: </TASK>
Apr 29 15:11:21 Raza kernel: ---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---


No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release: 22.04
Codename: jammy
Linux Raza 5.19.0-41-generic #42~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Apr 18 17:40:00 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

This is happening on an Acer Predator PT315-52:

```
description: Notebook
    product: Predator PT315-52 (0000000000000000)
    vendor: Acer
    version: V1.09
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-3.2.0 dmi-3.2.0 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: chassis=notebook family=Predator Triton 300 sku=0000000000000000

*-network
             description: Wireless interface
             product: Comet Lake PCH CNVi WiFi
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
             logical name: wlp0s20f3
             version: 00
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
             configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.19.0-41-generic firmware=72.daa05125.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-72.u ip=10.0.0.31 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
             resources: irq:16 memory:c2598000-c259bfff
```

I finally caught the boot log for one of those times when it failed to load. Here it is:

```sh
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: CSR_RESET = 0x10
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Host monitor block 0x0 vector 0x0
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 0]: 0x3f1d0430
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 1]: 0x3f1d0430
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 2]: 0x3f1d0430
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 3]: 0x3f1d0430
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 4]: 0x3f1d0030
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 5]: 0x3f1d0430
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 6]: 0x3f1d0030
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 7]: 0x3f1d0430
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 8]: 0x3f1d0030
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 9]: 0x3f1d0030
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 10]: 0x3f1d0030
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 11]: 0x3f1d0030
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 12]: 0x3f1d0430
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 13]: 0x3f1d0030
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 14]: 0x3f1d0430
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Host monitor block 0x0 vector 0x1
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 0]: 0x040066c2
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 1]: 0x040066c2
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 2]: 0x040066c2
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 3]: 0x040066c2
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 4]: 0x040066c2
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 5]: 0x040066c2
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 6]: 0x040066c2
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 7]: 0x040066c2
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 8]: 0x040066c2
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 9]: 0x040066c2
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 10]: 0x040066c2
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 11]: 0x040066c2
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 12]: 0x040066c2
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 13]: 0x040066c2
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 14]: 0x040066c2
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Host monitor block 0x0 vector 0x6
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 0]: 0xa00c7c75
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 1]: 0xf00c7c75
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 2]: 0xe00c7c75
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 3]: 0xa00c7c75
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 4]: 0xe00c7c75
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 5]: 0xa00c7c75
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 6]: 0xe00c7c75
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 7]: 0xa00c7c75
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 8]: 0xf00c7c75
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 9]: 0xa00c7c75
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 10]: 0xf00c7c75
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 11]: 0xb00c7c75
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 12]: 0xf00c7c75
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 13]: 0xb00c7c75
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 14]: 0xf00c7c75
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Host monitor block 0x22 vector 0x0
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 0]: 0x81cec019
Jun 05 06:35:03 Raza kernel: iwlwifi: probe of 0000:00:14.3 failed with error -110
```